# Determine if a script tag is in the head or body with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm querying for  tags with beautiful soup with

```
scriptResults = soup3('script')
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3)
```

How would I determine whether each script result found was in the head or body tags?

Would the easiest way be to extract the head, extract the body and then check for script tags in each separately?

Comment: extracting `head` and `body`  seperately can be done by `html_code.split('</head>')`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try that. Feel free to submit as an answer not a comment so I can flag you as having answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the source before passing to BS:

```
parts = html.split('</head>')
head = parts[0]
body = parts[1]

head_soup = BeautifulSoup(head)
body_soup = BeautifulSoup(body)
```

After this, simply check for the existence of the script tag in each soup.